# Setting Props on Imported Component via API

Tags: reactjs

Have searched for a solution to this [seemingly] simple problem, but being relatively new to Node, haven't quite figured it out.

I need to set a prop on an imported Component prior to it rendering. The value for the prop is dynamic and based on the response of an API.

Based on what I've read, this should occur in the Constructor of my umbrella "App", but have few issues:

1) the Component throws an error when the prop value is set by API
2) I think this is because React attempts to render the Component before the API call completes

The Component renders without error if I manually set a valid value.

So, wondering how to grab the value and set the prop before the Component renders to avoid the error.

I can post a code sample, but have tried so many variations I'm not sure they'd be that useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if I am misunderstanding this.

- You have two components, Component `Parent` and Component `Child`.
- Component `Parent` gets information from an API, and sends it to Component `Child`.
- Component `Child` renders depending on what you `Parent` sends to it

So, I believe the problem is that `Child` is not waiting for the API call to finish to render.

If I make an API call, I am not going to have the information for it immediately. You might want to handle the case where `Child` does not have the prop. To do that, you can call `Child` like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  // Make the request to the API and handle the response

  render(){
    //Set the result of the API call to state.itemFromApiCall
    return <div><Child item={this.state.itemFromApiCall} /></div>
  }
}
```

And your `Child` component would look like this:

```
function Child (props){
  if(!props.item)
    return <span>Loading...</span>

  //Then you have your component as you had before
}
```

On first Render, Child will not crash because it knows that `prop.item` might be `undefined`. Whenever you actually get the value of the API call, `Child` will behave as expected.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This didn't quite work for me. Just perpetually shows "Loading ...". However, it did lead me down the path of the answer that ultimately worked 

`<div className="explorer">
                { this.state && this.state.item &&
                    <Child
                        root={this.state.selected}
                        auth={this.state.item}
                        language="en-US"
                        logo=''
                        messages={messages}
                    />
                }
</div>`

Comment: I did have a colleague who recommended essentially the same solution as you proposed, so I'm going to mark this answered. Thanks for responding.